# ios-Changing image of several buttons on prototype cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a prototype cell inside a UITableview which contains 3 different buttons.

How can I programmatically change the background image of each button with a different image?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create IBOutlets from the buttons to the Class using Interface Builder.

You can then access the buttons' properties and set the image using UIButtons

> 

Swift

```
func setImage(_ image: UIImage?,forState state: UIControlState)
```

Objective-C

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state
```

Pass in the images for the states you want, default being

```
UIControlState.Normal
```

Comment: actually now im getting the error message: Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content

Comment: The outlets should be on a subclass of UITableViewCell that you use in your table view, not on the UIViewController itself.